Is repeating a test on fresh data until a statistically significant result is reached p-hacking?
I have a quantum random number generator and I wish to know if it can pass a set of statistical tests to check whether it’s truly random.
For this I use the Dieharder suite of tests.
In this suite, there is a flag to increase the number of repetitions of a given test until a statistically significant pass or fail is reached if the result is potentially non-significant. Crucially, this re-runs the test with additional samples of random numbers from the generator, not the same set of bytes.
Would using this count as p-hacking? If it would, is it actually a problem in this case?

I have asked the moderators to migrate this question to CrossValidated, where you might get better answers. You will likely get requests for clarification (e.g., what is that "source of randomness"?), perhaps you want to edit already to give more details in anticipation of the migration.

From a philosophical perspective, is there evidence that genuine randomness actually exists (at least in the macroscopic world), rather than randomness just being a mathematical model for dealing with ignorance (e.g. of initial conditions for a chaotic system or the seed of an RNG).  I would argue there isn't.  That means if you try hard enough, you will always get a significant outcome (perhaps for an infinitessimally small effect size) because we know the null hypothesis is false from the outset, so yes, it is p-hacking.

Basically, p exactly equal to 0.05 from an experiment where the cost of the experiment is linear in sample size is just a fancy way to report a null result in fields that otherwise prohibit publishing null results. If you are cynical you can use this information to publish, if you are sane then you have to use this information when interpreting results, including your own results but especially other’s results.

The question title "Is repeating a test until a statistically significant result is reached p-hacking?" hints at p-hacking. However, if it is well excecuted then sequential testing is not p-hacking. The description "to increase the number of repetitions of a given test until a statistically significant pass or fail is reached" is certainly not p-hacking by default as long as the 'probability to fail, conditional on the hypothesis being true' is managed to be within certain bounds. Reconsider the question, what did you ask precisely? Aside from being duplicate the point isn't very clear.

The 'Dieharder suite of tests' might need a better explanation. At least me, and I guess others, don't understand what you mean exactly.

I've added some clarifications

@Sextus Those tests are pretty well known--they have been around for decades.

@whuber I had to google that term and couldn't find it, but now I see that it wasn't difficult. Possibly I used as searchterm "dieharder suit" with quotation marks.

@SextusEmpiricus You don't need Google ;-).

@whuber I often search this website via google https://www.google.com/search?q=dieharder+site%3Astats.stackexchange.com it is more flexible when I make a spelling error (although it doesn't do this with dieharter) and I can browse based on images. The search function of the site has advantages with the extra options.

Let's see what can happen and perform a simulation. Below, I t-test increasingly large samples for nonzero mean, with the samples drawn from $N(0, 1)$ distributions, so a true null hypothesis. When the null hypothesis is true, p-values should be uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. The wrinkle is that, if the t-test does not reject (at a specified $\alpha$-level, set to the usual $0.05$ here) at the given sample size, I increase the sample size by one and try again, up to a sample size of $250$. A nitpick could be that such a similation is not required to reject by such a sample size, so I should give thought to what I would call the p-value in such a case, but that never happened in my simulation.
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024) # Getting close to time to change my seed!
R <- 1000
alpha_level <- 0.05
Ns <- seq(1, 250, 1)

ps <- rep(NA, R)

for (i in 1:R){
  print(i)
  for (j in 2:length(Ns)){
  
    x <- rnorm(Ns[j], 0, 1)
    p <- t.test(x)$p.value
    
    if (p <= alpha_level){
      ps[i] <- p
      break
    }
  }
}

d <- data.frame(
  pvalue = ps,
  ECDF = ecdf(ps)(ps)
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = pvalue, y = ECDF)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, col = 'red') +
  xlim(0, 1) +
  ylim(0, 1)
summary(ps)

Here is a plot of the distribution of p-values, in black, compared to the theoretical distribution of p-values for a true null hypothesis, in red.

This approach is extremely prone to rejecting, despite the fact that the null hypothesis is true.
Overall, YES, your idea is major p-hacking.
